# Error message while starting VS2012

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012

I'm using `Visual Studio 2012`, and I'm getting following message from Visual Studio in the start up:

> "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an
>   extension."

Checked the xml:

```
error msg:

<entry>
    <record>274</record>
    <time>2014/04/02 00:14:52.872</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at o.TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassc.&lt;BindContentTypeSpecificAssets&gt;b__9()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)</description>
</entry>
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to start VS in safe mode,
disable all the plugins you find there, 
restart VS in regular mode,
and try to enable them one by one (with restarting VS between each and every enable)

safe mode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

After you find the problematic plugin - please update you're request, or marked it as solved if you don't need this plugin and can uninstall it / leave it turned off.